# Same origin policy problem calling sharepoint web service

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, same-origin-policy

I am trying to call the pre-defined web services from the sharepoint server but am unable to due to the same origin policy problem and cannot find a solution to it. I tried setting document.domain to the server name and server port but instead it throws a DOM Security Error 18 which is also the same problem as the previous error. I am just trying to call the getLists method to test whether it works and the code is taken from a tutorial then I have seen online from [here](http://mydevexperience.wordpress.com/2011/05/08/sharepoint-list-access-part-i-how-to-access-sharepoint-list-web-service-using-jquery-entirely-client-side-only/). Any help much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

My code is as follow:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title></title>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.4.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function () {
document.domain = 'http://servername:serverport'
var soapEnv =
"<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'> \
<soapenv:Body> \
<GetListItems xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/'> \
<listName>Occupations</listName> \
<viewFields> \
<ViewFields> \
<FieldRef Name='Title' /> \
</ViewFields> \
</viewFields> \
</GetListItems> \
</soapenv:Body> \
</soapenv:Envelope>";

// Call web service
$.ajax({
url: "http://servername:serverport/_vti_bin/lists.asmx",
type: "POST",
dataType: "xml",
data: soapEnv,
complete: processListAccessResult,
contentType: "text/xml; charset=\"utf-8\""
});
});

// Process result
function processListAccessResult(xData, status) {
$(xData.responseXML).find("z\\:row").each(function () {
$("#data").append("<li>" + $(this).attr("ows_Title") + "</li>");
});
}

</script>

<ul id="data"></ul>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Ajax, your pages and your data MUST come from the same top level domain. There are a few ways around this:

- Actually use the same domain to serve your pages and your XML data.
- Use a proxy on your server to get the XML from the remote domain, and re-serve from the same domain as your pages.
- Lower security on your browser(s), or perhaps add the sites to listed sites. (never tried this myself as it's rarely an option unless it's for an intranet or something)
- Use JSONP instead of XML (this works around the cross domain policy)
- Use Yahoo Pipes or YQL to convert your XML to JSONP [like this example](http://jsfiddle.net/E6QTD/1/)

Comment: I agree with what you outline, but the single-origin restriction doesn't just apply to XML, it also applies to JSON and anything else.

Comment: Good point. I have edited my first sentence  to make it more accurate and less XML specific

Comment: is it possible to use a jQuery XML to JSON plugin and the pad the JSON to make in JSONP?

Comment: No, the cross-domain problem is in getting the data from the server in XML format, not in processing it once you have it. Would you like me to provide an example solution? If so please point me to an example XML

Comment: [Here is a jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/E6QTD/1/) of how to use YQL to convert XML to JSONP and work around the cross-domain security.

Comment: @Hong Yi, is that YQL solution acceptable for you, or are you still looking for another solution?

Comment: That solution works fine but right now I am unable to authenticate myself with the sharepoint server that I am working with and I asked the question here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6742184/form-based-authentication-using-javascript-for-sharepoint). Hope you can help me there too. Thanks a lot. Really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1):

The document.domain approach only works if both pages are from the same top-level domain and it won't work if the ports are different. From what I remember, it also won't work unless it's set on both pages which, in your case, doesn't apply since you're trying to retrieve XML, not HTML from both.

Otherwise, you'll have to go with Grezzo's reply above...

Answer (score 0):

Use [CORS](http://enable-cors.org/) which is Cross Origin Resource Sharing.