# Form Based Authentication using Javascript for Sharepoint

Tags: javascript, web-services, sharepoint, authentication, cordova

I am trying to create a web page using javscript that uses form based authentication to login to the sharepoint server but it keeps using NTLM which is windows based authentication. Is there anyway to allow form based authentication using javascript as this web page is for mobile and phonegap? Thanks in advance. Any help appreciated.

My code is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title></title>
<script src="jquery-1.6.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function () {
var soapEnv = "<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' xmlns:xsd='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' xmlns:soap='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'> \
  <soap:Body> \
    <Login xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/'> \
      <username>username1</username> \
      <password>password</password> \
    </Login> \
  </soap:Body> \
</soap:Envelope>"

// Call web service
$.ajax({
url: "http://servername:serverport/_vti_bin/authentication.asmx",
type: "POST",
dataType: "xml",
data: soapEnv,
complete: processListAccessResult,
contentType: "text/xml; charset=\"utf-8\""
});
});

// Process result
function processListAccessResult(xData, status) {
alert(xData);
alert(status);
}

</script>

<ul id="data"></ul> 

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If this page isn't being served from the same domain as your SharePoint site, this won't even work in the first place.  Also, have you verified that FBA has been configured correctly; and that you have a membership database set up?

Comment: The membership database has been setup and I have taken a look at it before. Why would this not work if it isn't being served from the same domain? I am running this file in file:// protocol so the origin access policy would not apply if this is what you are referring to. I am able to call the web service, it's just that I keep getting 401 Unauthorized error and am unable to authenticate myself but if I access the server home page, I am able to log myself in using FBA so the membership database should be set up correctly. Any solutions on this? Thanks. Appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem (401 unauthorized), took me ages to realize that it works like a charm once you downgrade your jQuery version. I now use jQuery 1.4.4. Maybe some higher version also works but I haven't tried this yet. Anyway, 1.4.4 should do the trick. Good luck!